# Separate mysql_query from foreach validation check php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

This is a snippet of my code. I essentially I have a new array I want to insert into tablename, but before I do that I validate the new stat figures against the old ones, confirm they are numeric and insert into a new row.

I realise what I have done, the mysql_query is inside the foreach loop, it inserts 5 rows all the same. I want it to only insert 1 new row.

How Do I take the mysql_query outside the loop yet keep the validation that the foreach loop provides before attempting to insert a new row?

```
foreach ($statnumber as $element) {
if ($statnumber != $LastWeeksStats && is_numeric($element)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (idproducts, stat1, stat2, stat3, stat4, stat5, superstat1) VALUES('8', '$statnumber[0]', '$statnumber[1]', '$statnumber[2]', '$statnumber[3]', '$statnumber[4]', '$statnumber[5]')") or die(mysql_error());  
    } else {
    echo "'{$element}' is NOT numeric or results same as last week", PHP_EOL;
}} 
mysql_close();
```

Comment: did you heard something about break keyword ?

Comment: it will end loop , so put it after your query ( so it will be done once and then end ) - but that situtation means you have mistake in design

Comment: yes I just google it, it looks like it would work, but as you say would be a bodge job.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the elements that fail the check from the array then have the mysql statement outside the loop at the end.  Use unset but you have to keep track of what keys to unset like this:

```
foreach ($statnumber as $key => $element) {
    if($statnumber != $LastWeeksStats && is_numeric($element)) {
       //do nothing because it is valid      
    } else {
       //remove that element from the array
       unset($statnumber[$key]);
       echo "'{$element}' is NOT numeric or results same as last week", PHP_EOL;
    }
}  
//now only valid data is in the array and you can use a mysql query
```

You will have to update the mysql query based on how many elements are actually in the array at the end like so:

```
foreach($statnumber as $key => $element) {
   $keys[] = "stat$key";
   $elements[] = "'$element'";
}
$keystring = implode(",",$keys);
$elementstring = implode(",",$elements);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (idproducts, $keystring, superstat1) VALUES('8', $elementstring)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Ah ok, so it potentially could remove all elements if, all elements match last weeks stats or are not numeric.

Comment: yes, anything which doesn't pass that test would get removed from the array before the mysql statement runs

Comment: It doesn't seem to work as I need it to, If all the elements match the lastweeks stats or if an element isnt numeric I need to to not insert data as its 100% wrong. Your code replaces the elemt with a zero and continues to insert a new row.

Comment: You will need to chage your mysql query, the elements are removed but if you are using the same mysql query then it tries to look up what is $statnumber[5] for example and when there is nothing there it replaces it with 0 instead.

Comment: It doesn't work, I don't want it to take an element I simply don't want it to insert a row at all if both of the arrays contain exactly the same elements or are not numeric